# Loading page twice with AJAX causes .on('click') to stop functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have a page that I am loading in with AJAX, a page like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    console.log('binding clickable');
    console.log($('#clickable').length);
    $('#clickable').off();
    $('#clickable').on('click',function(){
        console.log('hello');
    });
});
</script>
<h1>New Page</h1>
<p>Blah blah blah...</p>
<div class="button" id="clickable">OK</div>
```

So, when I load this page with AJAX it works fine.

When I load this page, and then load another page, and then load this page again, it works fine.

However, when I load this page, and then load this page again - the `#clickable` button doesnt work anymore.

When I look in the console I can see `binding clickable`, so the `$(document).ready()` function is being run ok. And beneath this in the console I can see the number `1`, so I know the jQuery selector `'#clickable'` is finding the DOM element ok.

I added the line `$('#clickable').off()` just in case the event was being bound to the DOM element twice. But this doesn't help.

Im loading the page with a standard `$.ajax({type:'GET',dataType:'text'});` call, this code works fine. The problem isnt how we are loading the page via AJAX, the problem is the page being loaded twice causes the `.on('click')` function to stop working.

We have already solved this problem by using PHP to add a random string to the end of the button tags `id` and jQuery selector, so I am assuming using the same selector for each page load is the problem, but I was hoping somebody with more knowledge could shed some light on this situation.

- Can somebody explain to me, why a second loading of the page is stopping the button from being clickable?

Comment: Try event delegation, the syntax is ```$( "body" ).on( "click", "#clickable", function( event ) { /*do something*/ });```, more info: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: @Varinder many thanks - looking into this and using it has worked for me! Put this as an answer and I will mark you as correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try event delegation, the syntax is:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#clickable", function( event ) { /*do something*/ });
```

more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)